# Strategy questions

Tags: discussion

Can we make a ***Strategy*** tag that will allow questions to have more than just a single correct answer?

Since strategies in unsolved games tend have more than one right answer.  I my mind, the best site to get board games-strategy discussion is still not exists.

The problem in Board & Card Games S.E is that questions are not open to a discussions, while the on [BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/) the strategy forums attracts low-quality posts and a lot of chit-chat nonsense.  I view the best discussion as a bunch of strategies that the best once gets more votes, thus go up and viewed first.

Related to:

- [How can I structure questions appropriately to learn more about
  strategy for the games I enjoy?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/how-can-i-structure-questions-appropriately-to-learn-more-about-strategy-for-the)
- [Should we close question that are just “what are good strategy tips
  for such-and-such game”?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/should-we-close-question-that-are-just-what-are-good-strategy-tips-for-such-and)
- [Are questions about statistics, math, analysis, simulations, numbers, chance, etc discouraged?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/405/are-questions-about-statistics-math-analysis-simulations-numbers-chance-et)

Comment: Something of note, I know in the past after winning a game I have heard you didn't play correctly which leads me to believe we would get debates over which answer is correct even if both may be valid

Answer (score 3):

Sure strategy questions can have more than a single correct answer but is that what we really want at this site? The problem is we are a question and answer site and once you start getting into multiple different answers for strategy that will tend to attract a lot of discussion and chit chat about the pros/cons, strengths/weaknesses and various other issues about each of the different strategies. I don't think that we would escape the chit chat that you are complaining about on BGG if we where to encourage this type of behavior on the site.

However that all said I would disagree with you about this site only being for a single correct answer as I have seen plenty of cases where there are multiple answers that disagree with each that could both be correct because there is nothing to state one is correct or wrong for the game in question.

In the end the problem with these question is they can tend to be overly broad and attract a lot of opinion based answers.